# Delphi XE2: Loading .EXE icon into MenuItem at run-time

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-xe2

At run-time, I want to load and show the main icon of a specific .EXE file in a specific MenuItem. When this is not possible for this specific .EXE file (e.g. due to access restrictions or similar), then the MenuItem icon should be set to a specific icon in a specific ImageList (e.g. MyMenuItem.ImageIndex := 7). How can this be done?

Comment: Use `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` to get a module handle with which you can then query for the first icon.

Comment: Do you mean:
`LoadLibraryEx(PChar(AExeFile), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);`
However, declaration of LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE is not found; where is it declared?

Comment: If you cannot find it in the RTL units that ship with Delphi, just look it up on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So far I'm stuck with this code:
    procedure SetMenuItemIconToMainIconFromExeFile(const AMenuItem: TMenuItem; const AExeFile: string);  
    const  
      LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = $00000020;  
    var  
      h: HMODULE;  
    begin  
      h := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(AExeFile), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);  
      if h <> 0 then  
      begin 
        
      end;  
    end;

Comment: Now you need to enumerate the icon resources. Use `EnumResourceNames` for that. You want the first icon.

Comment: OK, with `EnumResourceNames` I get from one exe:  
MAINICON  
MAINICON2  
MAINICON3  
MAINICON4  
SMALLICON  
and from an other exe:  
MAINICON  
What now?

Comment: Pick the first one. The rule is that the executable's icon is the first icon resource in the module.

Comment: OK, I pick the first one. What can I do with the string 'MAINICON'?

Comment: I've added an answer using a much simpler approach that does all the grunt work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use `ExtractIconEx`. Here's a very simple example:

```
type
  PHICON = ^HICON;

function ExtractIconEx(lpszFile: LPCWSTR; nIconIndex: Integer;
  phiconLarge, phiconSmall: PHICON; nIcons: UINT): UINT; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll' name 'ExtractIconExW';

function GetSmallIconFromExecutableFile(const FileName: string): TIcon;
var
  Icon: HICON;
  ExtractedIconCount: UINT;
begin
  Result := nil;
  try
    ExtractedIconCount := ExtractIconEx(
      PChar(FileName),
      0,
      nil,
      @Icon,
      1
    );
    Win32Check(ExtractedIconCount=1);
    Result := TIcon.Create;
    Result.Handle := Icon;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: But it has been reported by others that ExtractIcon/ExtractIconEx does not always work, especially with 64-bit executables?

Comment: You'll need to provide a citation for that. Very hard to see how it could not work.

Comment: Thank you, David! I've tried to use it with this code, but it does not work:  
`NewItem.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, GetSmallIconFromExecutableFile(ExeFilePath));`  
Where is the bug?

Comment: Don't do it that way. Add the icon to an image list and use the ImageIndex property of the menu item. Set Images on the main menu to the image list. You can use `MenuItem.Bitmap.Assign(...)` if you wish but you won't get transparency. I've now given you two answers to the question you asked. I hope you find them helpful.

Comment: OK, now it works; I have to put this line before the assignment:  
`NewItem.Bitmap.SetSize(16,16);`
Does this also work with 64-bit executables?

Comment: Yes it does. They use exactly the same format as 32 bit executables.

Comment: Wath is the drawback of doing it that way?

Comment: I don't think you can get 32bpp alpha transparency with `Bitmap`. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You are right: This way transparency does not work with 32bpp alpha icons.

Answer (score 2):

The icon associated with an executable file is the first one in the module. So you can extract it like this:

```
function EnumResNameProc(hModule: HMODULE; lpszType: LPCTSTR; lpszName: LPTSTR; lParam: LONG_PTR): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  HICON(Pointer(lParam)^) := LoadImage(
    hModule,
    lpszName,
    IMAGE_ICON,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
    0
  );
  Result := False;
end;

function GetFirstSmallIcon(hmod: HMODULE): HICON;
begin
  Result := 0;
  EnumResourceNames(hmod, RT_GROUP_ICON, @EnumResNameProc, NativeInt(@Result));
end;

function GetSmallIconFromExecutableFile(const FileName: string): TIcon;
const
  LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = $00000020;
var
  hmod: HMODULE;
  Icon: HICON;
begin
  Result := nil;
  try
    hmod := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(FileName), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    Win32Check(hmod<>0);
    try
      Icon := GetFirstSmallIcon(hmod);
      if Icon<>0 then begin
        Result := TIcon.Create;
        Result.Handle := Icon;
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(hmod);
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: David, you are the greatest! Which one of the two solutions you provided is preferable?

Comment: Personally I'd opt for `ExtractIconEx`.